# Intersected semi-transparent stroke text

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have an issue with the painting context.stokeText that style contains an alpha. A big value of line width makes some effect of intersected strokes, as a result, the color is darker.
How I can avoid this?

```
ctx.strokeStyle ="rgba(0,0,0,0.3)";                
ctx.lineWidth = 15;
ctx.lineJoin="round";                
ctx.strokeText(text, x, y);
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddg5L.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Letter spacing in canvas element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952909/letter-spacing-in-canvas-element)

Comment: I can't use latter spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bit of an inconsistency in the specs since usually [overlapping sub-pathes are painted only once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572223/3702797).

However `strokeText()` does [create one shape per glyph](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#text-preparation-algorithm), and thus this method will indeed paint each glyphs on their own, creating this visible overlapping.

To overcome this, you'll to be a bit creative:

- first draw your text fully opaque,
- then redraw the produced pixels with the desired alpha level (many ways to do so).
- draw that on your scene (or draw the background behind).

Here are a few ways (there are many others):

Probably the easiest, but which costs more memory: use a second disconnected canvas:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// create a new canvas just for the text
const canvas2 = canvas.cloneNode();
const ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
ctx2.font = "60px sans-serif";
const text = "MY TEXT";
const x = canvas.width - ctx2.measureText(text).width - 20;
const y = canvas.height - 20;
// draw it fully opaque
ctx2.lineWidth = 15;
ctx2.lineJoin="round";                
ctx2.strokeText(text, x, y);

// draw the background on the visible canvas
ctx.fillStyle = "#ffe97f";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// now draw our text canvas onto the visible one
// with the desired opacity
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.3;
ctx.drawImage(canvas2, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas width="465" height="234"></canvas>
```

More memory friendly, but which requires you to rewrite your drawing logic in a different direction, use [compositing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation):

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "60px sans-serif";
const text = "MY TEXT";
const x = canvas.width - ctx.measureText(text).width - 20;
const y = canvas.height - 20;

// first draw the text fully opaque
ctx.lineWidth = 15;
ctx.lineJoin="round";                
ctx.strokeText(text, x, y);

// now apply the opacity
ctx.fillStyle ="rgba(0,0,0,0.3)";
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// and the background
ctx.fillStyle = "#ffe97f";
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// if you want to keep drawing "normaly"
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
```

```html
<canvas width="465" height="234"></canvas>
```

A mix of both, with different compositing rules:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "60px sans-serif";
const text = "MY TEXT";
const x = canvas.width - ctx.measureText(text).width - 20;
const y = canvas.height - 20;

// first draw the text fully opaque
ctx.lineWidth = 15;
ctx.lineJoin="round";                
ctx.strokeText(text, x, y);

// now redraw over itself with the desired opacity
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.3;
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
ctx.globalAlpha = 1;

// and the background
ctx.fillStyle = "#ffe97f";
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// if you want to keep drawing "normaly"
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
```

```html
<canvas width="465" height="234"></canvas>
```